# more accuracy with sicpy interp1d

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to implement a non parametric estimation of the KL divergence shown in this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1fbd/31b690e078ce938f73f14462fceadc2748bf.pdf)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import itertools
import random
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def log(x):
    if x > 0: return math.log(x)
    else: return 0

g = lambda x, inp,N : sum(0.5 + 0.5 * np.sign(x-inp))/N

def ecdf(x,N):
    out = [g(i,x,N) for i in x]
    fun = interp1d(x, out, kind='linear', bounds_error = False, fill_value = (0,1))
    return fun

def KL_est(x,y):
    ex = min(np.diff(sorted(np.unique(x))))
    ey = min(np.diff(sorted(np.unique(y))))
    e = min(ex,ey) * 0.9
    N = len(x)
    x.sort()
    y.sort()
    P = ecdf(x,N)
    Q = ecdf(y,N)
    KL = sum(log(v) for v in ((P(x)-P(x-e))/(Q(x)-Q(x-e))) ) / N
    return KL
```

My trouble is with scipy interp1d. I am using the function returned from interp1d to find the value of new inputs. The problem is, some of the input values are very close (10^-5 apart) and the function returns the same value for both. In my code above, Q(x) - Q(x-e) leads to a divide by zero error.

Here is some test code that reproduces the problem:

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
ex = min(np.diff(sorted(np.unique(x))))
ey = min(np.diff(sorted(np.unique(y))))
e = min(ex,ey) * 0.9
N = len(x)
x.sort()
y.sort()
P = ecdf(x,N)
Q = ecdf(y,N)
KL = sum(log(v) for v in ((P(x)-P(x-e))/(Q(x)-Q(x-e))) ) / N
```

How would I go about getting a more accurate interpolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `e` gets small you are effectively trying to compute the ratio of derivatives of `P` and `Q` numerically. As you are finding, you run out of precision really quickly in floating point doing it this way.

An alternate approach would be to use an interpolation function that can return derivatives directly. For example, you could try [`scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html). You were saying `kind='linear'` to `interp1d`, so the equivalent is `k=1`. Once you construct it, the spline has method [`derivatives()`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivatives.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivatives) that gives you all the derivatives at different points. For small values of `e` you could switch to using the derivative.